# Do visa officers know about my previously filled incorrect DS 160?

Tags: f1-visas

I recently filled a DS 160 for F-1 visa and in that I checked "Yes" in the question "Do you have any other relatives in U.S.?". But I don't actually have blood relatives in the U.S., we just have a very close family friend (he is like a family but not blood related) in US. Now if I fill new DS 160 form and tick "No" for this question, will visa officer know what I filled in my previous DS 160 form?

Hoping for an answer from someone who is expert in this field(like retired visa officers or someone similar).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they have access to your previous fillings.

Does it matter? Probably no.

They check such inconsistencies? Probably no.
Usually consular officers have not much time to review all papers before the interview (time constraint to process a large number of applications), but they will check if you have sent too many applications, or you have too many rejections. Then just before interview or during interview they will look your application, and ask you some questions.  The application is just difficult to judge (also because most applicant are also not native speakers), so it is mostly an help for consular officer to have some basis to interview you. If they find something strange, they just ask for details.

Before making the decision will check again the documentation, and eventually ask you for further question (officially it is a reject, but it is a soft reject, you can amend documentation without redoing all steps).

Note: It is normal to have changes between applications. You may had a brother in US (e.g. for studies), but now it is back home, or the old uncle died, or a lot of other reasons. So, they will ask you if they have doubts (do not lie). The only case they will just reject you because your documents, if they are huge feeling that you are insincere (mainly because they see too many applications from you, or they see forged documentation, or huge error).

Comment: Giacomo, I think a few words have gone missing. Can you please check what you wrote?

Comment: Did they submit the previous one? It isn’t clear from their submission